# SSO for Web Applications Deployed in WebSphere Application Server 9.0

Tags: java, websphere, single-sign-on, jaas

I have configured LTPA2 Token in WAS 9.0 And successfully token is being Generated once I login to the WAS 9.0 console( http://washost:9060/admin), Now I need to use the token for my webapps deployed in WAS9.0 to login programmatically without user entering the details  again for login pages present in my webapps.

I have followed the [Link](https://www.keensoft.es/en/sso-using-ltpa-on-ibm-websphere-servers-part1/)

My Understanding is that we can use the WebSphere APIs to login programmatically.

I further read the IBM documentation by following the below links.

1.[Configuring programmatic logins for Java Authentication and Authorization Service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_j2clogin.html)

2.[Programmatic login for JAAS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_aumech.html)

I was unable to understand the documentation well. What steps should I  follow to achieve SSO in websapps using the LTPA token.